# How do I build ISO Week Number DataTable programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, datatable, iso, week-number

Anyone know how to built DataTable of week no?

I heard there has a lot of type of calculations for that, Gregorian or etc...
My needs are ISO Week No and bind to datatable depends on week no.

The DataTable has 2 columns : ISOWeekNo and WeekName

```
ISOWeekNo   WeekName
1           01 Jan 2012 To 07 Jan 2012
2           08 Jan 2012 To 14 Jan 2012
```

How do I build programatically in C# based on ISO Week No?

Comment: The problem is that the first ISO 8601 week does start on 02.01.2012 and not 01.01.2012. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 2):

```
// Set up DataTable
var dt = new DataTable();
var col1 = new DataColumn("ISOWeekNo", typeof(int));
var col2 = new DataColumn("WeekName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.AddRange(new[] { col1, col2 });
dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { col1 };

// Start with the first day of this year and check each day until next year.
var day = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
while (day.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
{
    var weekNum = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(day, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    if (!dt.Rows.Contains(weekNum))
        dt.Rows.Add(weekNum, string.Format("{0} to {1}", day.ToString("dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy"), day.AddDays(6).ToString("dd' 'MMM' 'yyyy")));
    day = day.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you code... But weeknum 52 is 01 jan 2012 to 07 jan 2012 and the dates between 23 dec 2012 and 31 dec 2012 are not included.

Comment: You asked for ISO week number. 2012/01/01 is in week 52 of 2011. Week 1 of 2012 starts on 2012/01/02. You can change `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek` to `CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay`, but then it won't be ISO.

Comment: brother I mean in december u can check the point. lost one week. Thanks for your kindly support